# PHP waiting till background process execution

Tags: php, background

I am calling a Python script from PHP as background process, however PHP is waiting until the script execution ends.

This what I did:

```
<?php
$script = "backproc.py";
$python ="C:\Python27\python.exe";
$command = "$python $scriptname $para1 $para2";
shell_exec($command . '2>&1 >out.log &');
?>
```

Why is it waiting for background process to complete?

Answer (score 1):

You must redirect the output

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

So on UNIX it would be eg

```
shell_exec($command . ' 2>&1 > out.log');
```

Comment: Python script not returning anything to parent process. So I just want to call it and no output required from script, then why it is waiting .Even though I redirected output to some file execution hang until the execution of program ends

Comment: take a look at php.net **Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.**

Comment: Output redirected to another file but still same problem

Comment: on WINDOWS redirction works **> a.txt 2>&1** and don't hang *&* at the end